# WiFi and the sampling rate of spectrum analyzer

Tags: power-spectral-density

I'm trying to understand the correlation between RF analyzesrs and WiFi.

Looking at the device's datasheet I see that it has a sample rate of (max.) 100msec.
[to my understanding, the device can measure the signal strength/power 10 times  (or less) per/each 1 second].

I understand that WiFi signals are being transmitted in bursts.
Hunderds/thousands transmissions per 1 second. 
Each transmission last for a very short time, 3-5micro-second.
That is to say, that each 1 second there is a signal transmission-pause-signal transmission-pause and so on.

Since the analyzer measure only 5-10 times each second, is it a **theoretical** possibilty that the device can miss [shall not measure] most of the signals?

Comment: Are you sure the sampling rate is not 100MSPS? that's 100 million a second - a bit more like it for an RF analyser.
To answer your question There is no chance that taking 10 samples a second will give any information about a WiFi signal. 
Further to this, WiFi data is transmitted using a either 2.4 or 5 GHz signals (I think it's FM - not sure about that though). So you will need to sample at at least 5GHz to se anything at all (10GHz for a 5GHz system) so even if I am right about the sampling rate of the analyser, it still wont be enough. I think you will need some specialist equipment.

Comment: If you link the device you have we can take a look at it for you.

Comment: The average is 100 milli-sec. There are some faster and much more expensiver devices that can sample abit faster, every 3mili-sec. ..etc.

Choose any of the RF spectrum analyzer from the right most table.

http://www.aaronia.com/products/spectrum-analyzers/

Comment: Those will see frequencies from 700MHz to 2.5GHz (the lowest of the table on the right) I think its the update that happens 10 times a second. So you would miss some data in the gaps. However, those just give a spectrum, I.E how much power exists in those bands, it will give no information about the bits contained within. What is is you want to do with it? Do you want to look at the data in the channel?